# Matlab parallel processing using a network computer

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, matlab

I'm familiar with `matlabpool`, and `parfor` usage, but I still need to speedup the computation.

I have a more powerful computer in my 1GB network. Both computers have R2010b, and have the same code and paths.

What is the simplest way to use both computers for parallel computation?

Example of the code I use today:

--- main.m---

```
matlabpool('open', 3);
% ...
x = randn(1e5,1);
y = nan(size(x));
parfor k = 1 : length(x)
    y(k) = myfunc(x(k));
end
```

--- myfunc.m---

```
function y = myfunc(x)
    y = x; % some computation
return
```

Comment: parallel for looping probably won't help you over multiple computers because it probably wasn't designed to run on a cluster, and probably expects threads to run within the same process.  This being said, I have no idea if it's true or not.

Comment: Parallel looping via PARFOR in MATLAB definitely is designed to run over multiple computers. It uses separate MATLAB processes rather than threads in a single process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For real cluster computing, you'll need the [distributed computing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/distriben/), as you can read on the [parallel computing info page](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/parallel-computing/):

> Without changing the code, you can run the same application on a computer cluster or a grid computing service (using MATLAB Distributed Computing Server™). You can run parallel applications interactively or in batch.

But installing (=buying) a toolbox just for adding one computer to the worker pool might be a bit too expensive. Luckily there are also alternatives: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13775

I personally haven't used this, but think it's definitely worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, but after spending some time I couldn't connect remote machine. I guess I'll return to this issue when it becomes critical.