# A concrete example of a parfor loop in Matlab that outperforms the for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am still somewhat new to parallel computing in Matlab.  I have used OpenMP in C successfully, but could not get better performance in Matlab.

First, since I'm machine at a university that I am new to, I verified that the machine I am on has the Parallel Computing Toolbox by typing `ver` in the command prompt and it displayed:  `Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 5.2        (R2011b)`.  Note that the machine has 4 cores

I tried simple examples of using `parfor` vs. `for`, but `for` always won, though this might be because of the overhead cost.  I was doing simple things like the example here: [MATLAB parfor is slower than for -- what is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174358/matlab-parfor-is-slower-than-for-what-is-wrong)

Before trying to apply parfor to my bigger more complicated program (I need to compute 500 evaluations of a function and each evaluation takes about a minute, so parallelizing will help here), I would very much like to see a concrete example where `parfor` beats `for`. .  Examples are abundant for OpenMP, but did not find a simple example that I can copy and paste that shows `parfor` is better than `for`

Comment: have you tried taking functions that take a long time to calculate? you can just make one that has a `pause(5)` in it...

Comment: did you set matlabpool before using `parfor`? For example: `matlabpool open 4`

Comment: @Serg:  No.  Does `matlabpool open 4` simply mean I want to use 4 cores?  If so, that would  be very helpful to know.  Also, would, for instance, `matlabpool open 3` mean I only use 3 out of the 4 cores?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf:  Yes, I have, though the example was complicated, which is why I wanted to check things with a simple example. I am now away from my work computer...I'll check your and Serg's suggestion tomorrow and get back

Comment: Well..Serg seems right since here: http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/distcomp/brb2x2l-1.html
it says that "Note   If matlabpool is not running, a parfor-loop runs serially on the client without regard for iteration sequence."  and I did not open matlabpool...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following code (once per Matlab session) in order to use `parfor`:

```
pools = matlabpool('size');
cpus = feature('numCores');
if pools ~= (cpus - 1)
    if pools > 0
        matlabpool('close');
    end
    matlabpool('open', cpus - 1);
end
```

This leaves 1 core for other processes.
Note, the `feature()` command is undocumented.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Tried remote login and it worked.  Thanks for helping me get started with `parfor` in Matlab.

Comment: @dblazevski You are welcome. What do you mean by remote login? Is it relevant to my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726156/matlab-parallel-processing-using-a-network-computer

Comment: Ah no, sorry...Before in one of my comments above I mentioned that I was away from a work computer.  I'm at a new job and I didn't know what the actual server name was so I figured I'd try again tomorrow...  Then after digging and guessing, I remotely logged in to test what you said.  So, no, not relevant, but was me to some extent thinking out loud.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example of improved performance from parfor on [Loren Shure's MATLAB blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/10/03/parfor-the-course/).

Her example is simply computing the rank of a magic square matrix:

```
function ranks = parMagic(n)

ranks = zeros(1,n);
parfor (ind = 1:n)
    ranks(ind) = rank(magic(ind));  % last index could be ind,not n-ind+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Serg describes how to "enable" parallel functionality.
Here is a very simple cut and paste example to test it with as requested. Simply copy and paste the follwing into an mfile and run it.

```
function parfortest()
enable_parallel;
pause on
tic;
N=500;
for i=1:N
    sequential_answer=slow_fun(i);
end
sequential_time=toc
tic;
parfor i=1:N
   sequential_answer=slow_fun(i);
end
parallel_time=toc
end
function result=slow_fun(x)
    pause(0.001);
    result=x;
end
```

If you have run the code to enable parallel as shown in the answer by Serg you should get a pretty obvious improvement in performance.